# generate 0 and 1 with 25% and 75 probability

Tags: matlab, bitwise-operators

i  have seen  the following problem one one site :

```
 how to  generate 0 and  1  with 25% and  75% probability, here is corresponding code in c++

int rand50()
{
    // rand() function will generate odd or even
    // number with equal probability. If rand()
    // generates odd number, the function will
    // return 1 else it will return 0.
    return rand() & 1;
}
 bool rand75()
{
    return rand50() | rand50();
}
```

but unfortunately i can't do

```
>> bitand(rand,1)
Error using bitand
Double inputs must have integer values in the range of ASSUMEDTYPE.
```

therefore i used following  algorithms 
1. rand50

```
function boolean=rand50()

        probability=rand;

        if  probability <=0.5
            boolean=0;
        else
            boolean=1;
        end

        end
```

2.rand75

```
function  boolean=rand75()
boolean=bitor(rand50(),rand50());

end
```

i think they are equivalent right?or at least well approximated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand` in C/C++ returns an *integer* whereas in MATLAB it returns a `double` between `0` and `1`. As you've shown, you can construct a function which will give you a value of `true` or `false` with equal probability using `0.5`, although it can be shortened to:

```
function bool = rand50()
    bool = rand() < 0.5;
end
```

That being said, I think I would recommend modifying your function a little bit to accept a dimension as input such that you can generate an arbitrary number of random samples at once. You can then test the output to make sure it is as expected

```
function bool = rand50(sz)
    bool = rand(sz) < 0.5;
end

function bool = rand75(sz)
    bool = rand50(sz) | rand50(sz);
end
```

Now we can test this

```
samples = rand75([10000, 1]);
mean(samples)
%   0.7460
```

Now if you ignore the code that you've shown, the better way to generate random numbers with a given frequency would be to create a function where you specify the percentage of 0's or 1's that you want and use that to compare to the output of `rand`

```
function bool = myrand(sz, percentage)
    bool = rand(sz) < percentage;
end

% Get 10 samples with 25% 1's
values = myrand([10, 1], 0.25);
```

Comment: Changing the "50" in the function name to an input variable would allow you to produce 0/1 distributed with arbitrary frequencies, e.g. 25%/75%

Comment: @Suever: Why use bit-logic, if you can just have `bool = rand()<0.75` for 75% zeros?

Comment: ii thanks in advance, i just  making equivalent  codes between matlab and c++

Comment: @Suever  of course  that is right, i  have did for single  output